# Why doesn't my parented smoke domain move with the parent object?

Tags: parent

I have parented a fireplace, the firewood (the smoke flow) and the smoke domain. Unfortunately, the smoke domain doesn't move along when I move my parent object. I can't move it separately either. It looks a bit weird to have a fire floating in the air. Does anybody have a solution?

[image]